# White lines through disabled views

Tags: android, view, line

Has anybody else seen this?  Whenever I have a view that is disabled I have a white line that goes through the view.  I feel like I got this after doing an update on my SDK but I'm not sure.Also, I saw a post on a google group that said it had to do with the height so I changed it to what they suggested and nothing happened.  Any ideas how to get rid of this?  Thanks.

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/etAmount"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true"
 />
```

In my code I create the field

```
EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
```

And then base on some boolean variable I set it enabled or disabled

```
etName.setEnabled(isOnce ? true : isSeries);
```

Comment: post ur code so that we can have a look

Comment: I've just updated the post with one of the views that has the white line.  I also see this on my spinners but code is basically the same.

Comment: its just an EditText whats wrong with this

Comment: well you can try one thing just change the background to smthng
android:background="#F0F0F0" and then see wat happens

Comment: I have no idea.  I was wondering if someone has seen this before.  The only thing I do in the code is myButton.setEnabled(false); and the white line appears.

Comment: this isnt your complete code, post your complete code and operation in class then i might try finding out,,,also myButton isnt shown in your above code,,myButton is button and above is edittext

Comment: Sorry about that.  I meant the EditText view.  I updated the post.